# TableViewController numberOfRowsInSection section

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller with buttons and a `TableViewController` with 10 arrays. Each button has an index, which pass to `TableViewController`.

In `TableViewController` code looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if buttonIndex == 0 {
        return array0.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 1 {
        return array1.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 2 {
        return array2.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 3 {
        return array3.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 4 {
        return array4.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 5 {
        return array5.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 6 {
        return array6.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 7 {
        return array6.count
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 8 {
        return array6.count
    }

    return array0.count
}
```

I want to automatically define current index to do this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return array(currentIndex).count
    }
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is by creating a map, with index as key and array as value.

So your code should look something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return indicesArray[index].count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make nested array where to store your arrays like:

```
var mainArray = [array0,array1,array2 ... ]
```

Then in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return mainArray[section].count
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to make the collection of your array in the array and you could be able to return as your requirement.**

**At class level:**

```
var arrOfArrayData = []
```

Just like that:

```
let array0 = [""]
let array1 = [""]
let array2 = [""]
let array3 = [""]
let array4 = [""]
let array5 = [""]
let array6 = [""]

arrOfArrayData = [array0,array1,array1,array3,array4,array5,array6]

return arrOfArrayData[section].count //numberOfRowsInSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list which contains 10 values as an array:

```
let listData = [["value11", "value12"], ["value21", "value22"], ["value31", "value32"] ...]
```

Inside UITableViewDataSource delegate method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return listData[section].count
    }
```